# You cannot define a correlation name 'CONSTANT_idx' more than once

Tags: php, magento, correlation

I have installed a magento extension called `Layered Navigation SEO` and got it to show. I just now have an error like below when I click a filter. I have looked in dozens of blogposts and stacks about this problem which just state that I should look for a double defined `catalog/layer_view` module. But I looked at a lot of different places, but there is just one of em, and still the problem keeps arising. Should I look for another double defined module? Or any other tips?

```
You cannot define a correlation name 'color_idx' more than once

Trace:
#0 /var/www/robbshop/lib/Varien/Db/Select.php(281): Zend_Db_Select->_join('inner join', Array, 'color_idx.entit...', Array, NULL)
#1 /var/www/robbshop/lib/Zend/Db/Select.php(336): Varien_Db_Select->_join('inner join', Array, 'color_idx.entit...', Array, NULL)
#2 /var/www/robbshop/lib/Zend/Db/Select.php(315): Zend_Db_Select->joinInner(Array, 'color_idx.entit...', Array, NULL)
#3 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php(104): Zend_Db_Select->join(Array, 'color_idx.entit...', Array)
#4 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/community/Simtech/Searchanise/Model/Resource/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php(33): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Attribute->getCount(Object(Catalin_SEO_Model_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Attribute))
#5 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/community/Catalin/SEO/Model/Catalog/Layer/Filter/Attribute.php(84): Simtech_Searchanise_Model_Resource_Layer_Filter_Attribute->getCount(Object(Catalin_SEO_Model_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Attribute))
#6 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(151): Catalin_SEO_Model_Catalog_Layer_Filter_Attribute->_getItemsData()
#7 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(120): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->_initItems()
#8 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(109): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItems()
#9 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/Filter/Abstract.php(132): Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
#10 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php(218): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_Filter_Abstract->getItemsCount()
#11 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Layer/View.php(233): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View->canShowOptions()
#12 /var/www/robbshop/app/design/frontend/rwd/innova/template/catalin_seo/catalog/layer/view.phtml(1): Mage_Catalog_Block_Layer_View->canShowBlock()
#13 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/robbsh...')
#14 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/rwd/in...')
#15 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#16 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#17 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#18 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#19 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#20 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('left', true)
#21 /var/www/robbshop/app/design/frontend/rwd/innova/template/page/2columns-left.phtml(31): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('left')
#22 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/robbsh...')
#23 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/rwd/in...')
#24 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#25 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#26 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#27 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#28 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/community/Catalin/SEO/controllers/CategoryController.php(92): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#29 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Catalin_Seo_CategoryController->viewAction()
#30 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/community/Catalin/SEO/Controller/Router.php(132): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('view')
#31 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Catalin_SEO_Controller_Router->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#32 /var/www/robbshop/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#33 /var/www/robbshop/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#34 /var/www/robbshop/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
```